# Output a sorted array using the Downtime class after a button was pressed from Form1

Tags: c#

Is there a way I could sort the "numbers" array into a new array followed by outputting that said sorted array using the Downtime class?

**Downtime Class**

```
public class Downtime
{
    float[] numbers = new float[5];
    private float sum;
    private float avg;
    

    public Downtime(float txtDowntime1, float txtDowntime2, float txtDowntime3, float txtDowntime4, float txtDowntime5)
    {
        numbers[0] = txtDowntime1;
        numbers[1] = txtDowntime2;
        numbers[2] = txtDowntime3;
        numbers[3] = txtDowntime4;
        numbers[4] = txtDowntime5;
    }

    public float Sum
    {
        get
        {
            return sum;
        }
        set
        {
            sum = value;
        }
    }

    public float SumArray()
    {
        foreach (float value in numbers)
        {
            sum += value;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public float Avg
    {
        get 
        { 
            return avg; 
        }
    }

    public float AvgArray() 
    {
        foreach (float value in numbers)
        {
            avg = numbers.Average();
        }
        return avg;
    }


    public float[] SortedArray()
    {
        Array.Sort(numbers);
        return numbers;
    }
    public float[] Numbers
    {
        get
        {
            return numbers;
        }
    }
}
```

**C# Code for Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Downtime downtime1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnAvgDowntime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Downtime calculate = new Downtime(float.Parse(txtDowntime1.Text), float.Parse(txtDowntime2.Text), float.Parse(txtDowntime3.Text),
            float.Parse(txtDowntime4.Text), float.Parse(txtDowntime5.Text));
        calculate.SumArray();
        calculate.AvgArray();


        outputAvgDowntime.Text = "Average downtime: " + calculate.Avg.ToString() + "\r\n" + 
            "Sorted downtime values are: " + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

I tried creating a method that sorts the array then it'll be referenced as a array of strings to be outputted on the output texbox. However, I was met with an error saying "System.Single[]". Other attempts involve using the ".ToString()" function and referencing the Downtime class with an object at the start of the Form1 code block which caused errors.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Downtime` class, modify the `SortedArray` method to return a string:

```cs
public string SortedArray()
{
    Array.Sort(numbers);
    return string.Join(", ", numbers);
}
```

In the `Form1` class, use the `SortedArray` method to get the sorted array as a string and output it:

```cs
private void btnAvgDowntime_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Downtime calculate = new Downtime(float.Parse(txtDowntime1.Text), float.Parse(txtDowntime2.Text), float.Parse(txtDowntime3.Text),
        float.Parse(txtDowntime4.Text), float.Parse(txtDowntime5.Text));
    calculate.SumArray();
    calculate.AvgArray();

    outputAvgDowntime.Text = "Average downtime: " + calculate.Avg.ToString() + "\r\n" + 
        "Sorted downtime values are: " + calculate.SortedArray() + "\r\n";
}
```

`SortedArray` method sorts the `numbers` array and then converts it to a string using the `string.Join` method. The resulting string is a comma-separated list of the sorted numbers. In the `Form1` class, the `SortedArray` method is called to get this string, which is then appended to the output string.